# React-webcam not working in React Native webview

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have my react application with the react-webcam library running on it, when I try to access the react app from a mobile app via webview and the camera just not working as expected. 
Any ideas, would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not work in standalone running ("installed") PWAs, getUserMedia returns no video input devices in UIWebView or WKWebView, but only directly in Safari

Source: https://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

Comment: Thank you for sharing the information. Any propose workaround solutions to have camera working on WebView?Just wondering?